# configure NGINX as a simple 2 ARM load balancer

Tags: nginx

I would like to configure NGINX as a simple 2 ARM load balancer. This is the target scenario:

[image]

I have tried this configuration:

```
 http {
  upstream backend1 {
    server 192.168.1.3;
    server 192.168.1.2;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend1;
    }
  }
}
```

but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide more detail info, for example: logs in nginx.error.log nginx.access.log

Comment: I have this error: "http" directive is not allowed here " /etc/nginx/site-enabled/default.conf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http` block redefined in `default.conf`, you could just keep server block in `default.conf` and move `upstream` to `http` block defined in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

1. Edit /etc/nginx/site-enabled/default.conf, just keep the `server` block

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://backend1;
    }
}
```

2. Edit /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, insert your `upstream` configure

```
http {
   ...

   // insert upstream before the following two `include` commands
   upstream backend1 {
    server 192.168.1.3;
    server 192.168.1.2;
   }
   
   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

3. Restart nginx `systemctl restart nginx` to make your changes take effect.

Comment: "http" directive is not allowed here in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:1`

Comment: it's `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`,  without `conf.d`, should already exsit